# NodeJS and MongoDB, high volume scheduled task

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am going to write a service using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) which everyday at 4 a.m. queries all users of my application and their activities (e.g. what they purchased, how many new users they brought etc.). This will lead to calculate score for each of them and send gifts accordingly. Since I have nearly 500,000 user records, I'm afraid that pulling all data with just one query ( like `User.find({})` ) becomes troublesome.

One solution that I can think of is to query users info with `skip` and `limit` features of mongoose along with a `setTimeout` in nodeJS and take for instance 1000 users at a time and then in 100 ms later next 1000 user and so on until I calculate all users scores and gifts.

Is this the right way or if this is not, can anyone suggest me a better approach?

Comment: Are you sure the 1st 1000 will finish within 100ms. Better might be to put the code in a function that calls itself again after the batch is processed

Comment: @Molda rather than waiting for 100ms, in each bunch i.e. each 1000, I will push my calls to an array which gives me an array of promises then I call the loop for next 1000 inside `Promise.all(arrayOfPromies).then()`. I think this works :).